# How can I get vertical scrolling in wrapped columns using display: flex?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I would like to make a vertical list with display flex on **multiple columns**, but it should be scrollable vertically. Another **important** thing, the direction should be **from top to bottom**; the second item should be at the bottom of the first one.

Last thing, I don't always have 20 sub-elements, it could be only two, and in this case I need to have them on only one column, not multiples... that's why I didn't use a CSS Multi-column layout solution and turned to flexbox.

I have tried with `overflow: auto` or with `overflow-y: auto` but neither one worked.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/r69onzhy/4/

As you can see, it's scrollable *horizontally*, but I would like to have it **vertically**.

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  width: 210px;
  height: 100px;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: auto;
}

li {
  width: 70px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Test 1</li>
  <li>Test 2</li>
  <li>Test 3</li>
  <li>Test 4</li>
  <li>Test 5</li>
  <li>Test 6</li>
  <li>Test 7</li>
  <li>Test 8</li>
  <li>Test 9</li>
  <li>Test 10</li>
  <li>Test 11</li>
  <li>Test 12</li>
  <li>Test 13</li>
  <li>Test 14</li>
  <li>Test 15</li>
  <li>Test 16</li>
  <li>Test 17</li>
  <li>Test 18</li>
  <li>Test 19</li>
  <li>Test 20</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove `flex-direction: column`

Change `overflow: auto;` to `overflow-y: auto;`

If you need 3 items per row use

```
li {
   flex: 0 0 33.33%;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, it works but it changes the direction ... I need the second item beeing at the bottom of the first ... not on the right

Comment: use `flex-direction: all-scroll;`

Comment: I don't know this property ... And I can't find it on the web. I tried it but my browser told me it was invalid...

Comment: there is no such property in the specification: https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-direction-property not sure where you got it. Inspect the code to see that it's invalid and remove it to have the same behavior without it. In other words, it's doing nothing

Comment: Sorry I didn't saw that on specification.

Comment: You can try css grid.

Answer (score 0):

```
ul {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  width: 210px;
  height: 100px;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;


  li {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

Comment: Ok, but as I said i would like **multiples** columns ... that's why I need the wrap ...

Answer (score 0):

You can consider the use of [`columns`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/columns) with an extra wrapper

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 210px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: auto;

}
ul {
  columns:3;
  list-style:none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

li {
 padding:5px 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper"><ul>
  <li>Test 1</li>
  <li>Test 2</li>
  <li>Test 3</li>
  <li>Test 4</li>
  <li>Test 5</li>
  <li>Test 6</li>
  <li>Test 7</li>
  <li>Test 8</li>
  <li>Test 9</li>
  <li>Test 10</li>
  <li>Test 11</li>
  <li>Test 12</li>
  <li>Test 13</li>
  <li>Test 14</li>
  <li>Test 15</li>
  <li>Test 16</li>
  <li>Test 17</li>
  <li>Test 18</li>
  <li>Test 19</li>
  <li>Test 20</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Yep, I was trying this way before using flex, but the thing is I don't always have 20 submenus, they could be only 2 and in this case I want them in one column but whith this solution they would be in multiples columns... That's why I turned to the flex solution...

Comment: @SimonTrichereau even with flexbox I don't think you can do it, to have a dynamic number of columns and a vertical scrolling. There is a lot of variable and the browser will never know when to consider more than one column and when to add the scroll.

Comment: Yes, I'm affraid that it's impossible ... But that's why I asked, to know if there was a solution...